# How to dynamically substitute a variable when calling an enum class in Pyhon

Tags: python, class, variables, enums

#Lets take this example.

```
class Animal(enum.Enum):
    dog = 1
    cat = 2
    lion = 3

# printing enum member as string
print ("The string representation of enum member is : ", Animal.dog)
```

The above code works perfectly.

Now I want to be able to do the following

```
ani = "dog"
# printing enum member as string
print ("The string representation of enum member is : ", Animal.ani)
```

The above code doesnt work. How can I achieve the above functionality where I can dynamically substitute with a variable

Comment: You cannot do that. But why would you want to do that? What is your use case?

Comment: You can’t, ani it’s just a variable holding string value and dog is enum constant of class Animal which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name lookup feature:

```
print ("The string representation of enum member is : ", Animal[ani])
```